# How to make Kindle Preview run on El Capitain

Tags: macos, kindle

Installed Kindle Previewer v2.94 but it doesn't open, just crashes without even an error message.

tried to solve using [this blog's instructions](http://epubsecrets.com/fixing-kindle-previewer-on-os-x-yosemite.php)

but it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 1):

I found this works 
(from [Apple's Java support note](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) )

1) Download and install X11
https://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac

2) Download and install Java for OSX
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

3)
finder>applications>(right click) kindle previewer.app>show package contents>contents>macos>
(Right click) Launcher>open with> other, choose textedit, then enter the following and save

```
#!/bin/sh

export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"

dir=`dirname "$0"`
cd "$dir"
classpath=./:./lib/touchLibs/etc/fonts/fonts

for i in `ls ./lib`
do
classpath=$classpath:./lib/$i
done

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

# start the previewer
fileExtT=`echo $1 | awk -F. '{print $NF}'`
fileExt=`echo $fileExtT | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

if [ "$fileExt" == mobi -o "$fileExt" == azw3 -o "$fileExt" == epub -o "$fileExt" == opf -o "$fileExt" == html -o "$fileExt" == zip ]
then
# opens only the first book in command line. TODO: handle multiple books in command line
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -d32 -XstartOnFirstThread -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "${classpath}" com.amazon.epub.reader.Main "$1"
exit 1
else
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -d32 -XstartOnFirstThread -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "${classpath}" com.amazon.epub.reader.Main
exit 1
fi
```

4)
(Right click) KindlePreviewer>open with> other, choose textedit> then enter the following and save

```
#!/bin/sh

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6
# start the autoupdate 
java -jar autoupdate.jar

./Launcher $@

dir=`dirname "$0"`
cd "$dir"
classpath=./

for i in `ls ./lib`
do
    classpath=$classpath:./lib/$i
done


# start the autoupdate  
java  -jar autoupdate.jar

./Launcher $@
```

Comment: It looks like a formatter somewhere has messed up the various commands entered in these sections, some of which need to be on separate lines.

Comment: This looks odd to me. I would have thought OSX Java programs cannot use X11 (has someone just copied Linux instructions?)

Comment: @Mark not sure, but I am following along trying to get the previewer to work on El Capitan.  I have Java 6 and Xquartz installed, then as soon as I added the JAVA_HOME bits to the first script the Amazon Kindle Previewer launched.  (I had previously tried starting it but it appeared to silently crash), so this answer seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I suspect it just needs Java 6 and the rest is unnecessary also even crash is recorded in the logs

Comment: I would also read the comments top the article - one says just need to use java 6 and I suspect there are easier ways - a later pone gives an Amazon released patch but no other info tho could be malware